# Error:The prefix "android" for attribute "android:versionCode" associated with an element type "manifest" is not bound

Tags: android, xml

Please Help me to fix this problem i have tried other solutions but i dont understand please solve this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ` `android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.1"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    package="com.abhimoviedownloadcom">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:debuggable="true" android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this: `xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to this: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Answer (score 1):

```
 ` `  android:versionCode="1"
 ^ ^
```

remove these if they are in your actual code.

Comment: Error:(2) Error parsing XML: unbound prefix